# Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined Error in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am new to AngularJS. I am using bootstrap validator to validate form in my project. It was working fine until I add the following code to my controller javascript file for validation:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#searchProducts').bootstrapValidator({
                message: 'This value is not valid',
                feedbackIcons: {
                    valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                    invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                    validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                },
                fields: {
                    keyword: {
                        message: 'The productname is not valid',
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'The productname is required and cannot be empty'
                            },
                            stringLength: {
                                min: 6,
                                message: 'The productname must be more than 6 and less than 30 characters long'
                            },
                            regexp: {
                                regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/,
                                message: 'The productname can only consist of alphabetical, number and underscore'
                            }
                        }
                    },

                }
            });
        });
```

I have included following javascript files in my master page as suggested [here](http://bootstrapvalidator.com/)

```
<script src="~/scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="~/scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="~/scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <script src="~/scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/scripts/angular-local-storage.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/bootstrapvalidator/dist/js/bootstrapValidator.js"></script>
```

It gives me error that "Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined" on my this code on master view page:

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin: 0 20px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div data-ng-view="" class="main"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Using jQuery/bootstrap-validation is what's wrong...

Comment: http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angularjs-form-validation

Comment: Yes, but I see it is working in the [bootstrapvalidator](http://bootstrapvalidator.com/). Can't I use it in my project ?

Comment: with a bit of quirky hacks you might pull it of... but angular has better form validation built in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is small example of how the angular validation works without a single line of javascript code

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
  <form name="myForm">
    search: <input type="search" ng-pattern="" required ng-model="searchTerm" name="query" ng-maxlength="30" ng-minlength="6">
    <div ng-if="myForm.$invalid && myForm.$dirty">
      The productname is not valid<br>

      <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.query.$error.minlength">
        The productname must be more than 6
      </span>

      <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.query.$error.maxlength">
        The productname must be less than 30 characters long
      </span>

      <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.query.$error.required">
        The productname is required and cannot be empty
      </span>
    </div>  

  </form>
</div>
```